# Filter results those are failed to converge

Tags: probability-or-statistics, algorithm

I have this code

```
amb3[a_, b_, g_, d_] = ProbabilityDistribution[ (Log[a] d b)/(a - 1)
     x^(-b - 1) (1 + g x^-b)^(-d/g - 1) a^(1 + g x^-b)^(-d/g) , {x, 
    0, \[Infinity]}];

Table[data = RandomVariate[amb3[3, 1.5, 2, 3.5], 50];
 ll = LogLikelihood[amb3[a, b, g, d], data];
 est = FindMaximum[{ll, a > 1.01, b > 0.01, g > 0.01, d > 0.01}, {a, 
    b, g, d}], {10}]
```

This code gives me ML estimates "10" times for sample size 50. I have to repeat this code 1000 time. As some results are failed to converge but their outcome is included in the result. I know this issue will be resolve by increases Number of Iteration and Precision Goal etc. If I increase the iterations same code takes more time which I cant afford. So I am looking for such solution which filter the failed to converge results.

Comment: check [Check](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Check.html)?

Comment: @kglr My original problem is to filter the values or bypass failed to converge values.

Comment: `Check[FindMaximum[...], failed]` returns `failed` if `FindMaximum[...]` generates any message. You can eliminate these using `Deletecases[table, failed` (assuming  `table = Table[ ...]`)

Comment: @kglr Thanks, its work.

Comment: SAAN , posted the comment as answer.

Comment: The "good" MLE's aren't worth much if 80% of the MLE's don't converge.  Reparameterizing the probability density function might be helpful.

Comment: Just use the true parameter values as starting values and the issue might disappear completely.  I used `{{a, 3}, {b, 1.5}, {g, 2}, {d, 3.5}}` for 100 times and all converged with no warnings.

Comment: @JimB Yes I agree true values help us, but if we dont have any idea about initial values same problem occur often.

Comment: But that just means you'll need to make additional guesses until you get convergence (or maybe discover that the model is overparameterized or undersampled).  Also because the default starting value is 1.0 for all parameters (if you don't give any explicit starting values), you'll need to at least give a legitimate starting value for `a` (which your constraints state must be greater than 1.01).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Check](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Check.html)

[image]

```
table = Table[data = RandomVariate[amb3[3, 1.5, 2, 3.5], 50];
 ll = LogLikelihood[amb3[a, b, g, d], data];
 Check[FindMaximum[{ll, a > 1.01, b > 0.01, g > 0.01, d > 0.01}, {a, b, g, d}], 
  failed], {10}];
DeleteCases[table, failed]
```

Answer (score 3):

**THIS IS AN EXTENDED COMMENT RATHER THAN AN ANSWER.**

```
$Version

(* "11.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)" *)

amb3[a_, b_, g_, d_] = 
  ProbabilityDistribution[(Log[a] d b)/(a - 1) x^(-b - 1) (1 + 
       g x^-b)^(-d/g - 1) a^(1 + g x^-b)^(-d/g), {x, 0, ∞}];
```

Your distribution does not appear to be well-behaved with `RandomVariate` as evidenced by failure of  the `Mean` and `StandardDeviation` to converge with increasing sample size.

```
SeedRandom[40];
data = (RandomVariate[amb3[3, 1.5, 2, 3.5], #] & /@ (10^Range[6]));

Mean /@ data

(* {6.58196, 4.88944, 6.7506, 7.51826, 7.67877, 3.43141} *)

StandardDeviation /@ data

(* {5.41989, 5.07194, 14.1477, 26.0551, 32.155, 7200.92} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm glad I learned about `Check` but it turns out to be unnecessary in this case.  What counts is good starting values.  Just use the known values as starting values and everything works fine.  1,000 simulations took about 47 minutes on my desktop Windows PC.

```
amb3[a_, b_, g_, d_] = 
  ProbabilityDistribution[(Log[a] d b)/(a - 1) x^(-b - 1) (1 + 
       g x^-b)^(-d/g - 1) a^(1 + g x^-b)^(-d/g), {x, 0, \[Infinity]}];

AbsoluteTiming[
 mle = Table[data = RandomVariate[amb3[3, 1.5, 2, 3.5], 50];
   ll = LogLikelihood[amb3[a, b, g, d], data];
   est = FindMaximum[{ll, a > 1.01, b > 0.01, g > 0.01, d > 0.01},
   {{a, 3}, {b, 1.5}, {g, 2}, {d, 3.5}}], {1000}]]
```